# How to recover package.json from node_modules directory

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I deleted the `package.json` in mistake but I have `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` directory and when I give the project files to my coworker he will get some errors when he wants to use `gulp` (because I use Macbook and my coworker uses Windows). So I think he should install all `node_modules` in his machine.

Is there any way to create package.json from `package-lock.json` or `node_modules` directory?

Comment: Well the lesson here is this is why you use source control. Fortunately you would be able to obtain "some" of the data from the `package-lock.json`, but it's not everything. Any scripts or metadata would be lost. I would suggest learning git or similar as a priority. Or do you actually have git or similar enabled?

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for your comment, yes I use `git` in my projects but this project was for a previous developer and they have given me this project to continue But I do not remember that I removed the `package.json` or that it did not exist from the beginning

Comment: First off did you check to make sure that it's not in your recycle bin (or trash I think is what it's called on mac)? Also you could probably manually install them all going through the node_modules one by one and the package.json, but it's pretty tedious.

Comment: Well wer're pretty much checking down the options since "rebuilding" a `package.json` based on `package-lock.json` is a process you need to create. It's not like it's "built into npm" or anything like that. So `git` or "Recycle Bin" would be the most conveinent methods. And like I said, there's other data in `package.json` that is not listed in `package-lock.json`. The **big** difference being "dependencies" vs "devDependencies" as the "lock" does not distinguish between the two

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same problem, but I got it!

Just do `npm init -y` it will again generate the `package.json` file using your `node_modules` or from the `package-lock.json`.

Comment: can you feel it? i just telepathically sent you the joy of 100 high-fives for your most excellent problem solving skills... I knew there had to be a way to get the package.json from a yarn.lock and re-running `init` did the trick

Comment: LOL I love the last comment :D